# NiFi ReplaceText: strip all xml tags between specific tags

Tags: regex, xml, apache-nifi

I have the XML document below. I want to strip out all the tags between `<TXT>` and `</TXT>` to make a raw text tag in NiFi so the raw text reads like a sentence. I tried the following regex pattern in the ReplaceText processor in NiFi but the process failed--even though it captured the full txt section on regex101.com. What have I done wrong?

Client would prefer to use the built-in NiFi processors to do this rather than implement a script.

**Regex**

```
<TXT.*>((.|\n)*?)<\/TXT>$
```

**XML**

```
<DOC>
<ID>12345</ID>
<TXT>
    <A><DESC type="PERSON">George Washington</DESC> lived in a house called <DESC type="PLACE">Mount Vernon</DESC></A>
</TXT>
</DOC>
```

ReplaceText configurations are as follows

```
Search Value: <TXT.*>((.|\n)*?)<\/TXT>$
Replacement Value: <RAW>$1</RAW>
Character Set: UTF-8
Maximum Buffer Size: 1 MB
Replacement Strategy: Regex Replace
Evaluation Mode: Entire text
```

**Ideal output**

```
<DOC>
<ID>12345</ID>
<RAW>George Washington lived in a house called Mount Vernon</RAW>
</DOC>
```

Comment: In your first regex pattern you have `\n` (newline) but the pattern in your configuration contains `\N` (negation of newline, basically the opposite of `\n`). It should work if you just use `\n` in the configuration. That said, `<TXT.*>[\S\s]*?<\/TXT>` is a bit simpler. Also, are you sure NiFi's TransformXML processor isn't more appropriate for this?

Comment: @CAustin I fixed the \n, it auto-capitalized when I pasted it in here for some reason. The reason I have the regex I have is group it isolates a group which is needed for replace text. And I never even thought of using TransformXML; would I just make an xslt for that?

Comment: If you need the inner text in a capture group, you can just put `()` around the `[\S\s]*`. I don't actually use NiFi myself so I can't provide details on how to use TransformXML but it looks like this was designed to do what you need, and in general regex is bad for parsing XML.

Answer (score 0):

First, disclaimers:

- XSLT Transformation could be what you want
- A script could be what you want

To my knowledge, you can't do recursive regexp in NiFi. So you would need to chain processors :

- One processor to replace `<TXT>([\S\s]*?)<\/TXT>` by `<RAW>$1</RAW>`
- One processor to route on content on `<RAW>[\S|\s]*?<[\S|\s]*?</RAW>` (If RAW contains an inner tag)

  - If unmatched, you're good
  - If it matches, remove the first tag using an other replaceText `(<RAW>[\S\s]*?)(<[\S\s]*?>)([\S\s]*?</RAW>)`

This really seems overkill though, and since your text is annotated, it is likely that your client is already using Python somewhere, and should not be afraid of scripts.